# Laravel: How to get JSON objects with names separeted by "-"?

Tags: arrays, json, laravel

How can I get `{{ $cSiacon->'NOME-CLIENTE' }}` if it is dash separated? I´ve tried ['NOME-CLIENTE'] but Laravel gives me:

```
ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Cannot use object of type Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse as array
```

In my code:

```
$responseClienteSiacon = $clienteSiaconSOAP->ROS_ValidarCliente($paramClienteSiacon);
$cSiacon = response()->json(($responseClienteSiacon->ValidarCliente->Cliente));

return $cSiacon;
```

The result is:

```
[
{
"CODIGO-TIPO-PESSOA": "J",
"CPF-CNPJ": "00635344000177",
"CODIGO-GRUPO": "07384",
"NUMERO-SEQUENCIA": 0,
"NUMERO-COTA": 853,
"NOME-CLIENTE": "AUTO ESCOLA GUILHERMITTI E L LTDA",
"NUMERO-CONTRATO": 859866,
"DESCRICAO-BEM": "HONDA NXR 160 BROS",
"VALOR-BEM": 12975,
"NUMERO-TELEFONE": "017 32581859",
"DATA-PROXIMA-REUNIAO": "20190322",
"SITUACAO-COBRANCA": "N",
"DESCRICAO-SITUACAO-COBRANCA": "Normal",
"FASE-SITUACAO-COBRANCA": "N000",
"CODIGO-PLANO-COTA": 31,
"DATA-ENTREGA": "20180507",
"DATA-CONTEMPLACAO": "20170622",
"PERC-TOTAL-PAGO": 87.7196,
"PERC-TOTAL-PENDENTE": 3.1401,
"PERC-QUITACAO": 12.2804,
"CODIGO-FORMA-PAGAMENTO": 1,
"DATA-NASCIMENTO": "",
"DATA-CANCELAMENTO": "",
"CADASTRO-ATUALIZADO": "N",
"SEGMENTO-CADOC": 4,
"CEP": 15115000
},
{...
}
]
```

Also I´ve tried to get a higher position like: json(($responseClienteSiacon->ValidarCliente)); but the problem stils the same: the dash separated attribute name.
Should I convert each name before?

Comment: yes php keys can not have - in their name. Replace them by underscore _.

Comment: You can try by replacing the ```-``` to ```_```

Comment: @daremachine I did convert to '_' all right. The result now is:
```HTTP/1.0 200 OK Cache_Control: no_cache, private Content_Type: application/json Date: Mon, 11 Mar 2019 13:39:23 GMT {"CODIGO_TIPO_PESSOA":"F","CPF_CNPJ":"53958055672","CODIGO_GRUPO":"04921","NUMERO_SEQUENCIA":0,"NUMERO_COTA":47,"NOME_CLIENTE":"ROSIMEIRE DA SILVA ...}```
Then {{ $cSiacon->NOME_CLIENTE }} returns as a non-obejct.
As you can see, I am a little dumb sometimes ´cause I am an auto-didata on programming. Thanks for your understanding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this

```
$object->{'NOME-CLIENTE'};
```

POC

https://3v4l.org/cTO7o

Example using **blade**

```
@php
    $json = <<<JSON
    [
        {
            "CODIGO-TIPO-PESSOA": "J",
            "CPF-CNPJ": "00635344000177",
            "CODIGO-GRUPO": "07384",
            "NUMERO-SEQUENCIA": 0,
            "NUMERO-COTA": 853,
            "NOME-CLIENTE": "AUTO ESCOLA GUILHERMITTI E L LTDA",
            "NUMERO-CONTRATO": 859866,
            "DESCRICAO-BEM": "HONDA NXR 160 BROS",
            "VALOR-BEM": 12975,
            "NUMERO-TELEFONE": "017 32581859",
            "DATA-PROXIMA-REUNIAO": "20190322",
            "SITUACAO-COBRANCA": "N",
            "DESCRICAO-SITUACAO-COBRANCA": "Normal",
            "FASE-SITUACAO-COBRANCA": "N000",
            "CODIGO-PLANO-COTA": 31,
            "DATA-ENTREGA": "20180507",
            "DATA-CONTEMPLACAO": "20170622",
            "PERC-TOTAL-PAGO": 87.7196,
            "PERC-TOTAL-PENDENTE": 3.1401,
            "PERC-QUITACAO": 12.2804,
            "CODIGO-FORMA-PAGAMENTO": 1,
            "DATA-NASCIMENTO": "",
            "DATA-CANCELAMENTO": "",
            "CADASTRO-ATUALIZADO": "N",
            "SEGMENTO-CADOC": 4,
            "CEP": 15115000
        }
    ]
JSON;

    $json = json_decode($json);

@endphp

    {{-- will echo "AUTO ESCOLA GUILHERMITTI E L LTDA" --}}

    {{ $json[0]->{'NOME-CLIENTE'} }}
```

Comment: Very cool this 3v4l site @cbaconnier! But I must show it in a blade view!

Comment: @MarcelloPatto This is exactly the same thing, but instead of using `print_r` use `{{ $object->{'NOME-CLIENTE'}; }}`

Comment: OK, I´ll try and let you guys know in a minute!

Comment: Oh no! Didn´t work!
```
<h1>Parabéns <strong>{{ $cSiacon->{'NOME-CLIENTE'} }}</strong>! Você foi contemplado!</h1>
```
The result is:
```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse::$NOME-CLIENTE
```

Comment: Hold on. You're working on a JsonResponse? You're doing something wrong I suppose.

But assuming your Json **object** is at the root of your JsonResponse, you can try  something like `{{ $cSacon->getContent()[0]->{'NOME-CLIENT'} }}`  (did you noticed the `[0]` ? You're using an array on your example) But since we don't have all the information you're sending, you will have to figure out yourself how correctly access from `JsonResponse` to `$object`

Comment: @MarcelloPatto I have updated my answer with the exact ouput you give us and the exact result you expect. This works for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189819/discussion-between-cbaconnier-and-marcello-patto).